# preventing authentication failure popup (http 401) on closed network - http basic

Tags: jquery, firefox, basic-authentication

I'm facing this issue on a closed net at work.

I'm building something like LastPass and if the user's user/pass credential stored in my data store is no longer correct, when my code applies it via ajax (jQuery) login, the pesky 401 popup appears.

In my situation, I cant request that the site I'm logging into change their http error response.

I'd like to gracefully present customer defined error handling to the user.

Answer (score 1):

(Quote from http://techfuzionwithsam.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/avoiding-browser-popup-for-401/)

- Change the server response to not return 401. Return a 200 code instead and handle this in your JQuery client.
- Change the method that you're using for authorization to a custom value in your header. Browsers will display the popup for Basic and Digest. You have to change this on both the client and the server.
- headers : { "Authorization" : "BasicCustom" }
- Alternatively, if you can customize your server response, you could return a 403 Forbidden.
- The browser will not open the authentication popup and the jquery callback will be called.

Comment: Above link was redirected to http://techfuzionwithsam.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/avoiding-browser-popup-for-401/